# Create a suffix tree in golang

Tags: go

I have an array of strings and I need to create a suffix tree out of it in Golang.
SuffixArray in Golang does not suffice my needs, because it only accepts byte array (i.e of a single string).
Could anybody provide pointers for implementation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to create a suffix tree out of the compilation of all the strings or do you want a suffix tree for each element of the array?

Comment: @Ben Echols :One suffix tree which will make it possible to search on all strings.I will be using it for auto completion feature for a website.

Comment: `SuffixArray` already uses pointers in its implementation. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use suffix array to do auto completion. ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/RYsHwhHZ06)).

Note that I joined all the strings together with a prefix of `\x00` which can't occur in the strings first.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "index/suffixarray"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    words := []string{
        "aardvark",
        "happy",
        "hello",
        "hero",
        "he",
        "hotel",
    }
    // use \x00 to start each string
    joinedStrings := "\x00" + strings.Join(words, "\x00")
    sa := suffixarray.New([]byte(joinedStrings))

    // User has typed in "he"
    match, err := regexp.Compile("\x00he[^\x00]*")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ms := sa.FindAllIndex(match, -1)

    for _, m := range ms {
        start, end := m[0], m[1]
        fmt.Printf("match = %q\n", joinedStrings[start+1:end])
    }
}
```

Prints

```
match = "hello"
match = "hero"
match = "he"
```

Comment: Thanks for the implementation. If you could explain why is \x00 used to start each string,it would be great. Also if I want to handle the 2 cases ,1)if user enters "ello" then it should match "hello" 2) if the words array has "hello world" and user enters "wor", then it should display "hello world", how will the code change.

Comment: This example is good w.r.t. combining multiple strings into a single `byte[]`, however note that your regex pattern beats the purpose of suffix arrays since you're only looking at the start of words. For looking at prefixes you don't need anything so powerful as a suffix array - just sort your original strings and do a binary search. The true power of suffix arrays is finding matches *within* words, not just starts

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called generalized suffix tree. A simple way to build such trees is to append a different end marker(symbols not used in any of the strings) to each strings, concatenate them and build a normal suffix tree for the concatenated string. So you just need to add "hello world" to the string set and use:

```
match, err := regexp.Compile("[^\x00]*wor[^\x00]*")
```

to get the strings contain "wor". Note that the correct string is `joinedStrings[start:end]`.

Answer (score 0):

I created implementation of suffix tree with O(n) complexity, where n is length of string: https://github.com/twelvedata/searchindex

More details in my article on Medium https://medium.com/twelve-data/in-memory-text-search-index-for-quotes-on-go-5243adc62c26